# installing zlib for postgres on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

i've installed postgres on ubuntu and am trying to do a pg_dump but get the error message:

"pg_dump: [archiver] WARNING: requested compression not available in this installation -- archive will be uncompressed"

i've read that this is because i didn't install zlib along with postgres.

how can i install zlib for postgres now that postgres is already installed?

thanks.

**EDIT: command:**

```
pg_dump myDb -U myUser --schema=public --format=c --compress=9 > somefile.dmp
```

it's because of the --format=c, but i would like to have it compressed (which custom (c) does by default).

Comment: Can you post the command line you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not because of the --format=c, it's because of the --compress=9. You can use custom format without compression.

How did you install your PostgreSQL? If it was from the standard Ubuntu packages, it should have compression. If it was from source, you need to recompile with zlib available - remember to have the developer package. Normally, this would only happen if you explicitly configured it with "--disable-zlib".

Comment: yes compiled from source, will try re-compiling. thx.

Answer (score -2):

Folks, this is solved for after updated zlib-devel in centos. 
- Mohammed Azfar

Comment: The poster has an Ubuntu system, centos doesn't really apply.